# сравнение 2-х дат

Tags: php

Здравстуйте, такая задача при регистрации в бд заносится дата в формате 
date('Y-d-m') через месяц кроном беру текущую дату в формате date('Y-d-m')
Мне нужно сравнить эти две даты и за 3 дня месячной подписки отправить сообщение.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php 

$day2 =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', date('Y-d-m'))->getTimestamp(); // текущая дата
$day1 =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', '2018-01-02')->getTimestamp(); // Дата с которой сравниваем, например из БД

$diff = $day2-$day1;

$diff = floor($diff/(60*60*24)); // переменная diff содержит разницу дней

// ну и далее выполняете необходимые проверки которые нужны вам, и выполняете нужные действия

if ($diff >= 27) {
 echo "отправка сообщения\n"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: А не используя ООП можно как нибудь?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php - да не вопрос, можете использовать функцию в процедурном стиле, в мануале есть примеры.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.gettimestamp.php - и это тоже нужно прочитать

Comment: у меня в базе есть  3 строки
2018-03-01
2018-03-03
2018-03-03
далее в цикле foreach я по ключу data сравниваю с твоим вариантом решения .
echo $diff = floor($diff/(60*60*24)).'</br>';
Выводится 
60
1
1

Comment: Если сравнение идет с сегдняшней датой то все верно
2018-03-01 - прошло 60 дней
2018-03-03 - прошел 1 день.

Comment: Как все верно?
Регистрация бала 3 дня назад ,а он показывает 60.

Comment: Прочитайте ваш вопрос. Там указан формат
date('Y-d-m') 
Y - год
d - день
m - месяц
2018-03-01 - Так вот, следуя вашему формату, регистрация была 3-го января.